# Why a class in App_Code/BLL is not accessible in pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I have a class in folder App_Code/BLL/Countries.cs ,which is a public class.
But when I tried to access the class in a ASP.NET page like:

```
Countries MyCountries = new Countries();
```

its showing error:

"The type or namespace name 'Countries' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you're missing a using directive or an assembly reference? ;)

Comment: whats the namespace of you class?

Comment: namespace BGridNDynamicPage ..I m using the same namespace in page also...

Comment: You can't be or else you wouldn't get this error. Are the classes in different assemblies?

Comment: Right click the file and ensure the Build Action of the file is set to "Compile"

Answer (score 0):

Ok your countries class will look something like this

```
namespace  BGridNDynamicPage1
{
   public class Countries()
   {

      ......
   }
}
```

and your code above will be something like this:

```
using System.Web;
etc.
namespace BGridNDynamicPage
    {
       public class something() : Page
       {

          Countries MyCountries = new Countries();
       }
    }
```

change your second class too:

```
using  BGridNDynamicPage1;
using System.Web;
etc.

 namespace BGridNDynamicPage 
        {
           public class something() : Page
           {

              Countries MyCountries = new Countries();
           }
        }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks for ur quick reply....
but I still have that problem.
The type or namespace name 'BGridNDynamicPage1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your namespace is `BGridNDynamicPage1` not `BGridNDynamicPage`. so change the using statement to `using BGridNDynamicPage1`

Comment: all the classes are in BGridNDynamicPage1 namespace.
and all the pages in BGridNDynamicPage Namespace.
and yes I used BGridNDynamicPage1...still showing the error.

Comment: Ok, edited answer to reflect your namespaces. If this doesn't work then your classes and pages must be in a different assembly. So you'll need to add a reference to your "classes" assembly in your pages assembly. Right click on "references folder in your pages assembly and select "Add Reference" add your classes assembly here.